# How to get layout tab ajax request parameter in block?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0.7

I want to send productId when vendor tab is clicked . 
`vendor_section` current ajax url is :- `dailydealadmin/index/vendor`. 
But I want this url like this :- `dailydealadmin/index/vendor/productId/5`.

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
            <title>Daily Deal</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="menu">
                <action method="setActive">
                    <argument name="itemId" xsi:type="string">RB_Dailydeal::dailydeal</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceContainer name="page.main.actions">
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher" name="store_switcher">
                    <action method="setUseConfirm">
                        <argument name="params" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                    </action>
                </block>
            </referenceContainer>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="RB\Dailydeal\Block\Adminhtml\Deal\Edit" name="deal_edit"/>
            </referenceContainer>
            <referenceContainer name="left">
                <block class="RB\Dailydeal\Block\Adminhtml\Deal\Edit\Tabs" name="deal_edit_tabs">
                    <block class="RB\Dailydeal\Block\Adminhtml\Deal\Edit\Tab\Deal" name="deal_edit_tab_form"/>
                    <action method="addTab">
                        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">main_section</argument>
                        <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">deal_edit_tab_form</argument>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addTab">
                        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_section</argument>
                        <argument name="tab" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Product</item>
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Product</item>
                            <item name="actionPath" xsi:type="string">dailydealadmin/index/product</item>
                            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">ajax</item>
                        </argument>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addTab">
                        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vendor_section</argument>
                        <argument name="tab" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Vendor</item>
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Vendor</item>
                            <item name="actionPath" xsi:type="string">dailydealadmin/index/vendor</item>
                            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">ajax</item>
                        </argument>
                    </action>
                </block>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```